# Windows 10: sometimes sleep = shut down?

Tags: windows-10

Often times when I put my computer to sleep before going to bed, I discover when turning it on in the morning that it restarted completely with all my programs shut down. Why is that?

Comment: take a look at your update settings. Windows 10 is super aggravating about restarting without much warning to install updates. I have mine set to notify me long before it wants to restart so that I can delay it, and then reboot manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very likely, your computer was brought out of sleep to install windows updates and restart the computer.

If you open your start menu and head to `Settings` then go to `Updates and security` you'll see when your system was last updated. At this screen you can also change how the update settings work and disable it somewhat.

If you really want to stop windows updates from doing their job (Yes, I hate it enough that I have done it myself) you can go to `Control Panel` > `Administrative Tools` > `Services` and find the `Windows Updates` service. You can then set it to disabled. Do note when this service is disabled, windows updates stop working completely. It is not wise to never update your system. So once in a while, you will want to set it to enabled, update your system, reboot, and disable it again. If you don't there will be a point in the future where a virus or spyware can infect your pc because you did not install a security hotfix.

Comment: So either you lose your stuff through Windows restarting without permission, or you risk security issues by forgetting to manually updating your system. Thanks Microsoft for yet another brilliant example of magnificent logic.

Comment: @drake035 depends. If you choose not to use the recommended settings, microsoft will inform you when it will reboot about a day in advance, where it gives you the option to reschedule. You can then reschedule up to a week in the future, and if you revisit the windows update settings page 5 days later, you can reschedule another week. But it really is recommended to update windows and thus reboot before then. Its just that sometimes you cannot just reboot at that time.